# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error for HTTP API Gateway in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have a API Gateway that is linked to a lambda function written in python on AWS which returns some data. I can access the data no problem from a Google Sheets call. However when I try to access it locally (using a javascript 'fetch' call) I get a CORS error in the console:

"from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I have tried configuring the CORS settings in my AWS HTTP API GATEWAY like this, per previous SO posts:

[image: AWS HTTP API CORS config]

I've tried manually adding the headers to include 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'  to my lambda function (python). This didn't work, and per AWS, the headers from the lambda function are ignored and overridden by the API CORS configuration.

It seems like the AWS CORS configuration isn't being recognized. I've tried manual deployment and auto-deployment. Here's the response I get:

[image: Response headers]

I'm by no means an expert at this, and I've run out of ideas!

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing from your local machine, have you tried adding "http://localhost:*" into "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"?

I think this should fix your issue as you are coming from localhost.
Obviously this should be removed after you test and see that it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).